# Single advancement within bigger strategy

Tags: vocabulary

Which word could I use to denote a single advancement within a bigger strategy?  For example, "a recent `?` in my mission to improve my English was to..."

I was thinking of the word `gambit` but, according to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gambit), it connotes an opening character of the move whereas I wish to keep that aspect agnostic by my choice of word.

Comment: Perhaps "tactic."

Answer (score 3):

Step? Advance? Move? I do not think this is an exhaustive list but it may help.